# error message not showing if enter wrong username in the azure developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

[image: Hello Azure Users,]

Hi Everyone,
If I enter the wrong username and password in the Azure developer portal. It is not showing an error message. Can you please help with this?

The expectation is when I enter the wrong username and password, It should show.
You have entered the wrong username or password.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying with the Deprecated Developer Portal ?

Comment: In the deprecated developer portal, It is showing the error message.

Answer (score 1):

- I have  tried to login to the Developer Portal with the URL -
  https://**yourAPIMName**.developer.azure-api.net/signin.
- I got the Error message if the credentials are entered wrong.

[image]

- I have tried with the Deprecated developer portal as well.

[image]

- Please check once again from your end.

Comment: @A engineer, do let me know if the information provided helped you in solving your problem ?